# What does command `sed -i "s/^ \+//g; s/ \+/\t/g"` mean?

Tags: sed

I'm new to `sed`. Can someone help me to explain following sed command?

```
sed -i "s/^ \+//g; s/ \+/\t/g"
```

I found the explanation for the `-i` option on Google, but no exact explanations for the above pattern meanings.

Sorry that I don't have example file to show here due to the reason that our in-house server recently is under maintenance, which means I cannot access to the example file that needed here.

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: It is true that manpage of sed is hard to read and too brief. `s/A/B/g` means replace A with B. Read the output of `info sed 'sed scripts' 'The "s" command'` or https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html

Comment: `-i` will make sed modify the file, `s` command is the search &replace (substitute). The elements are separated with the `/` chars. Have a look to this exelent page: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: The overall effect of these two commands is to remove space(s) from the front of a line and replace each group of one or more spaces with a tab. The first command is slightly wrong in that it uses the global flag of the substitution command `g` and since the regexp is anchored to the start of the line by the `^` metacharacter, regexp can only match once, unlike the second substitution command which can match zero or more times. The use of the `\+` is similar to `*` in that it matches one or more rather than zero or more of the preceeding group of characters or as in these cases a space char.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what it means:

- `-i` - apply modifications to the input file directly
- `"s/^ \+//g;` - remove all spaces at the start of each line
- `s/ \+/\t/g"` - after the first replacement, replace all space strings with tabs

Comment: Big thx! I have been recently reading tutorials for awk and sed programming. Your answer is exactly the correct and very helpful!

Comment: Incidentally, the `g` flag on the first `s` command is useless, as the match can only occur once per line. The meaning of `g` is to replace all matches on a line, but if there is never more than one, the flag can't do anything.

Comment: Perhaps also point out that `\+` means "one or more matches". In modern ERE regular expressions, this is simply `+`, but in POSIX BRE (which is what `sed` supports out of the box) you (weirdly) need a backslash in front.